# Change position of App title in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I would like to change the position of the title of my app to be on the right of my icon in my action bar (as it is in the gmail android app). Currently, the app looks like:

[image]

I would like the vertical bars to appear to the left of the app title. My current styles.xml is:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
   <item name="android:logo">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

and my menu xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_menu"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_36dp"
      android:title="Menu"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ic_launcher_icon or the default app icon ?
Check your drawables and if its not there ,store one in it.

Then you'll definitely see your Action Bar title on the right side of your app icon.

Answer (score 0):

For doing so below is my code hope it will hepl you..

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionbar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
actionbar.setCustomView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_bg, null),
            new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    Gravity.CENTER
            )
    );
```

and create your custom view,what ever you want using xml file.
below is my xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/btn_bg_color">

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/left_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh_btn"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

  <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/right_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/logout_btn"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```